# Understanding the $ in Java's format strings

Tags: java, formatter

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 // Send all output to the Appendable object sb
 Formatter formatter = new Formatter(sb, Locale.US);

 // Explicit argument indices may be used to re-order output.
 formatter.format("%4$2s %3$2s %2$2s %1$2s", "a", "b", "c", "d")
 // -> " d  c  b  a"
```

In this case, why is a 2 appended to $?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

The `2` has nothing to do with the `$`:

- `%`     =   Start of format string
- `4$`   =   Fourth argument ('d')
- `2`     =   width of two (right-aligned)
- `s`     =   type of String

Comment: That really crisp explanation thanks. However, when I use %4$2s and my argument value is 'ABCDEFGH' it is not retrieving only 2 characters. It retrieved full string. Why?

Comment: 2     =   width of two (right-aligned)

Answer (score 50):

The `2$` means put the second argument from the list here.  The `$` *follows* a number not precedes it.  Similarly, `4$` means put the forth argument here.

To clarify, we can break down the `%2$2s` format into its parts:

- `%` - indicates this is a format string
- `2$` - shows the second value argument should be put here
- `2` - the format is two characters long
- `s` - format the value as a String

You can find more information [in the documentation](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

Comment: It was actually downvoted, when it was a wrong answer. As it is correct now, downvote removed.

Comment: @Sven - The answer never changed, I think you must have read it wrong.   I've added to but not changed any content.

Comment: Well, when I downvoted it read: "The 2$ means put the second argument from the list here." That's not what I would count as a correct answer.

Comment: It still says exactly that now and you've said its now correct.

Comment: On itself, it's wrong or at least not answering the question, but put into context, it's right.

Answer (score 4):

Those are positional arguments where `%4$2s` signals to format the *fourth* argument as a string with width 2. This is especially helpful when providing strings for localization where arguments need to be reordered without touching the source code.

> The format specifiers for types which are used to represents dates and times have the following syntax:
>
> ```
> %[argument_index$][flags][width]conversion
> ```
>
> The optional `argument_index` is a decimal integer indicating the position of the argument in the argument list. The first argument is referenced by `"1$"`, the second by `"2$"`, etc. —[Formatter documentation](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

Comment: Still, I like .NET's format strings better as they make the position of arguments much clearer.

Answer (score 4):

`%`: format string

`4$`: fourth value argument

`2`: width (length when argument is printed)

`s`: it's a string argument conversion

for example, the following snippet:

```
StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();

Formatter formatter=new Formatter(sb,Locale.UK);

formatter.format("-%4$5s-%3$5s-%2$5s-%1$5s-", "a", "b", "c", "d");

System.out.println(sb);
```

produces an output of :

```
-    d-    c-    b-    a-
```

(width of 5 characters per argument, padded with spaces)

and replacing `5` with `2`, will produce the following output:

```
- d- c- b- a-
```

See the difference? :)