# Java adding "0" at the end of the number

Tags: java, string, formatting, zero-padding

So my problem was such that I had to compute 10^n such that n ~ 10^5. Obviously it wouldn't fit in any data type hence I decided to use a string instead.
Finally, I did find the solution in the beginners book 
https://beginnersbook.com/2014/07/java-right-padding-a-string-with-spaces-and-zeros/.

I don't want the `BigInteger` solution of multiplying 10 n times.

```
public class PadRightExample2 {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        System.out.println("#" + rightPadZeros("mystring", 10) + "@");
        System.out.println("#" + rightPadZeros("mystring", 15) + "@");
        System.out.println("#" + rightPadZeros("mystring", 20) + "@");
    }

    public static String rightPadZeros(String str, int num) {
        return String.format("%1$-" + num + "s", str).replace(' ', '0');
    }
}
```

Output:

```
#mystring00@
#mystring0000000@
#mystring000000000000@
```

Can anybody explain what is `%1$-` and what is `s` used for ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding the $ in Java's format strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915074/understanding-the-in-javas-format-strings)

Comment: I didn't understand after going through that that's why I asked .

Comment: I'll highly appreciate if somebody answers this :)

Comment: Did you try reading the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) regarding the formatter?

Comment: `Obviuosly it wouldn't fit in any data type` - this is wrong. Use [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for numbers of any size.

Comment: @Robert Best answer off all! BigDecimal will get as large as you'd like (Until your computer/JVM doesn't run out of memory of course)... You should provide this as answer... Somebody should up vote your comment!

Comment: @0x1C1B Except that OP want a result like `#mystring0000000@` and `BigDecimal`/`BigInteger` cannot help build that. I mean, Robert is right, `BigDecimal` can be used numbers of any size, but `0000000` is not "a number of any size", since numbers in computers don't have a defined number of leading zeroes.

Comment: @Andreas Sure but if I understand him right, he just use this because of "no data type would fit" the size of his calculation and that's wrong there is an easier way just use `BigDecimal` and prevent this elaborate and "error-prone" string calculation or Does I understand him wrong?

Comment: @0x1C1B Yes, you understand wrong, so let me ask you: How would you implement `rightPadZeros("mystring", 15)` to return `mystring0000000` using `BigDecimal`? Because that is what OP wants.

Comment: @Andreas Yea sure you're right! But I'm sure @Robert wasn't intend to solve the string calculation issue, instead he tried to prevent a elaborate string calculation and solve it in a more efficient way (And you wouldn't deny that `BigDecimal` is the easier way or?)... If you strict try to answer the original question than of course `BigDecimal` isn't a fitting answer you're right

Comment: @0x1C1B Which was my point in commenting your comment for Robert to write it as an answer. Robert was appropriately commenting that *"wouldn't fit in any data type"* is an incorrect statement, since `BigDecimal` can do that, but `BigDecimal` is not a solution for the problem, and hence is not an answer to the question, so your suggestion to write it as an answer was misguided.

Comment: @Andreas Last statement: The devil is in the detail. You're right it was a good improvement but **not** a fitting answer

Comment: I stand corrected . BigDecimal/BigInteger can be used but for this particular case I want to avoid it .I wanted sth which could do the thing in one line . Like I've posted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `%` stands for the format of String
- `1$` means the first additional parameter `args` of `String.format(String format, Object... args)`, `2$` would be the second one, etc..
- `-` is the left justification, in connection with number declares the length of the final output, briefly said. The documentation of [java.util.Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) explains is a bit better:

  > Left justifies the output. Spaces ('\u0020') will be added at the end of the converted value as required to fill the minimum width of the field.
- `s` stands for the String parameter type

The typical example is logging, where you parse the arguments with `%s` which is practically the same. With a dollar character and number `%1$s` you specify the argument number and `-10` makes the final output length of 10.

```
#mystring00@            // mystring00 has length 10
#mystring0000000@       // mystring0000000 has length 15
#mystring000000000000@  // #mystring000000000000 has length 20
```

Most of the information could be found in the documentation of [java.util.Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html), which is used within `String::format`.

---

The snippet you have found might be a bit confusing because it works even without `1$` because the arguments are passed in order.

Try the following: `String.format("%2$-" + num + "s", str, "test").replace(' ', '0');`. The result will be

```
#test000000@
#test00000000000@
#test0000000000000000@
```

Whereas `String.format("%1$-" + num + "s", str, "test").replace(' ', '0');` leads to the original result from your snippet. Notice the `1$` and `2$` difference.

Comment: You might want to edit it to say that `s` is actually the parameter type. Would make it simpler for someone who doesn't understand it correctly.

Comment: @chromaerror: Right, thanks... that is more precise.

Comment: the first String argument is "String str" over here?

Comment: @SushantPradhan: Yes, that is.

Comment: @SushantPradhan if you do not know how to distinguish parameters, I would whole-heartedly recommend you to do something more basic, instead of this. For example, going through some basic java tutorials.

Comment: thanks @chromaerror for the advice but I'll pass on it ;)

Comment: @SushantPradhan Doesn't sound wise, but do as you please.

Comment: @SushantPradhan: Take a look to the edited part of my answer explaining why you can omit `1$` in your snippet.

Comment: *"`$1` means the first additional parameter"* Didn't you mean `1$`?

Comment: @Andreas: A bunch of typos. Thank you for your eagle eyes :))

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I'm not understanding the question correctly, but cant you do:

```
public static String rightPadZeros(String str, int num) {
    String add = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < num;i++) add += "0";
    return str + add;
}
```

I dont quite understand why you would want two zeros when `num=10`, but if you want that, do:

```
public static String rightPadZeros(String str, int num) {
    String add = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < num - 8;i++) add += "0";
    return str + add;
}
```

**EDIT**: apparenetely that was bad for performance, so this might be better:

```
public static String rightPadZeros(String str, int num) {
    return str + new String(new char[num]).replace("\0", "0");
}
```

Comment: my num~10^5 so doing this exceeded the time limit constraint of the question . :(

Comment: Then you can do `return str + new String(new char[num]).replace("\0", "0");` if you don't want to use a for loop.

Comment: String += String in a loop, 10000 times? Bad for performance.

Comment: Yeah, thats what @SushantPradhan said as well. That's why I improved it.

Comment: @PieterMantel thanks man ! It's easier to understand than the previous solution ! XD

Comment: @SushantPradhan I dont want to take all the credit, I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4903603/7132142)