# Multiple values String format Android

Tags: android

I would to display text like this sample : "0/2 documents"
I'm trying to do this with :

```
<plurals name="documents_get">
    <item quantity="one">%1d/%2d doucment</item>
    <item quantity="other">%1d/%2d documents</item>
</plurals>

resources.getQuantityString(
                    R.plurals.documents_get,
                    docCount,
                    documents.filter {

                        it.retrieved_at != null

                    }.count(),
                    docCount)
```

My problem is the result is :  `0/ 2 documents` instead "0/2 documents". Space after the '/' is the problem.

Do you know a solution for this ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the format you are using (`%2d`). So change your plurals to this:

```
<plurals name="documents_get">
    <item quantity="one">%d/%d doucment</item>
    <item quantity="other">%d/%d documents</item> 
</plurals>
```

Example with using `String.format`

```
String s1 = String.format("%d/%d document", 0, 1); // s1: "0/1 document"
String s2 = String.format("%d/%2d document", 0, 1); // s2: "0/ 1 document"
```

**Edit**

As @Kingfisher Phuoc noted, it should be `%1$d/%2$d` instead of `%d`. The $ sign allows you to specify the index of the string (the position where the string should be printed, called "explicit argument indices" or "positional arguments". You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915074/understanding-the-in-javas-format-strings)).

For example:

```
String s1 = String.format("%1$d/%2$d", 1, 2); // s1: "1/2" 
String s2 = String.format("%2$d/%1$d", 1, 2); // s2: "2/1"
```

Comment: Thank's i have replaced %1d/%2d with %d/%d

And don't know why i have put this 1 or 2 .

Comment: it should be %1$d/%2$d instead of %d.

Comment: @KingfisherPhuoc yes you are right. Edited my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove (%2d) and replace it with (%d) or you can use string format

```
String resource = String.format("%d/%d document", 0, 1); // s1: "0/1 document"
```

Answer (score -2):

You can define your string inside string.xml like this

```
<resources>
    <string name="string">0"/"2 documents</string>
</resources>
```

and fetch it via getResources.getString method.

**Note : Special Characters are enclosed inside double quotes.**